# Sorting Tweepy Status objects?

Tags: python, sorting, twitter, tweepy

I'm using `Tweepy` to get a list of trending topics. It's basically a list of current tweets with the highest number of retweets. When the API object returns my list of tweets, I get a list of `Status` objects.

I need to sort those `Status` objects according to the number of retweets. The property is `retweet_count`. I don't know how to do it properly because built-in sort methods won't work because this is a nested object

Here is what I have so far:

```
def getTrendingTopics(self):

'''
Get popular tweets by getting current tweets.
Sort the tweets according to the number of retweets, from high to low. 
Return the 15 most popular tweets in a list.        
'''

      trendingTopicsList = {}
      publicTweets = self.api.home_timeline()

      for tweet in publicTweets:
           retweetCount = str(len(tweet.retweets()))
           ##Sort Tweets here?
           print(tweet.text + "\n Retweets: " + retweetCount + "\n")

        #return the tweets in a list
```

Returning the tweets is easy enough, but how would I sort them?

I've tried a few ways to do it, but none worked. I left that code out.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I know little about tweepy, but if you need to get info out of json objects, there's a `json` module. https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: After that, it's just finding the right key function to give to sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use python [sorted](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Ascending_and_Descending) applying it to your `tweet` object. See code below with toy example.

```
In [1]: 
class Tweet:
    def __init__(self, text, retweets):
        self.text = text
        self.rt = retweets

    def retweets(self):
        return self.rt

In [2]:    
t1 = Tweet("text1", 2)
t2 = Tweet("text2", 17)
t3 = Tweet("text3", 3)
l = [t1, t2, t3]
[t.text for t in l]

Out[2]:
['text1', 'text2', 'text3']

In [3]:    
from operator import methodcaller
lsorted = sorted(l, key=methodcaller('retweets'), reverse=True)
[t.text for t in lsorted]

Out[3]:
['text2', 'text3', 'text1']
```